# Como calcular taxa custodia tesouro direto

Tags: microsoft-excel, matemática

Considere o seguinte investimento:

```
Capital inicial (C)   = 1000,00 reais
Juros (J)             = 12% ao ano
Período (n)           = 8 anos
Taxa de Custódia (TC) = 3% ao ano
```

A taxa de custódia (TC) é uma taxa cobrada anualmente sobre o montante acumulado até então. Ela é cobrada à parte e não influencia no montante.

Por exemplo: no 3º ano o montante será `M3 = C*(1+J)^n = 1404,93` e o valor de custódia será `VC3 = M3*TC = 42,15`.

Segue abaixo uma tabela com os valores de custódia calculados para cada ano:

[image: Valores de Custódia a Cada Ano]

Consigo calcular o total que pagarei de custódia somando as 8 linhas da tabela acima.

Ou seja:

```
Soma Custódias (SC) = VC1 + VC2 + VC3 ...
SC = M1*TC + M2*TC + M3*TC ...
SC = TC*(M1+M2+M3...)
```

Assim, chegamos à seguinte fórmula:

[image: Fórmula]

**Minha pergunta é:**

É possível obter uma fórmula de Excel que calcule a soma dos valores de custódia?

Gostaria de uma fórmula que fosse possível colocar em uma célula do Excel e que fizesse referência somente às variáveis `C`, `J`, `n` e `TC`, sem ser necessário criar uma tabela com os cálculos parciais.

**Para ser mais claro:**

Só quero preencher as quatro variáveis citadas no começo da pergunta (`C`, `J`, `n` e `TC`), cada qual em uma célula, e quero ter outra célula que calcule o resultado. Sem necessidade de tabelas.

Comment: Um somatório é representado no Excel pela função SOMA (SUM, se o seu Office estiver em inglês). Você tem que ter todas os elementos a serem somados em sequência, i.e.: em uma mesma linha ou coluna. Daí você pode fazer algo do tipo =SOMA(A1:F1), por exemplo, que somaria o valor de todas as células no intervalo.

Comment: Mas para ter os elementos somados em sequencia eu teria que criar uma tabela, certo? Teria uma forma sem criar uma tabela? Uma fórmula que utilizasse somente as variáveis C, J e n (que estariam cada uma em sua célula)?

Comment: O complicado é que não sei se as fórmulas do Excel têm alguma estrutura de laço. Mas acho que há uma resposta correta para a sua pergunta e espero que você a consiga.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth pelo que entendi ele só quer preencher as quatro variáveis citadas no começo da pergunta e ter o resultado, sem ter que preencher uma planilha. É útil porque se você for variar a quantidade de anos envolvida você não tem que mexer nas informações da planilha. Isso seria algo trivial com um pequeno codigo em Javascript ou VBA, mas creio que o OP tem como requisito fazer isso em Excel puro.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Sei que criar uma tabela em Excel é fácil. Porém, gostaria de saber se existe uma função no Excel que equivaleria à função de somatória da Matemática. Neste caso, não precisaria de tabela e não seria mágica, seria simplesmente uma implementação de um recurso matemático pelo Excel.

Comment: @Viniciusmss já tentou adaptar sua formula usando PGTO?

Comment: @Renan Exatamente isto Renan. Só quero preencher as quatro variáveis citadas no começo da pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: agora sim, adicione esse detalhe a pergunta, to tentando uma bruxaria aqui no excel pra ver se da certo

Comment: @Viniciusmss calculei de varias formas diferentes, mas pelo que me parece é impossível... não encontrei uma forma de repetição de função escalonada dentro da função soma(ao meu ver seria a única possibilidade). Conclusão que cheguei pra resolver seria: Calcular o VC1, no VC1 você aplica o J e terá o VC2, no VC2 aplica o J e terá o VC3 e assim por diante, agora só precisaria de uma forma de fazer isso automaticamente N vezes e somar todos esse resultados. não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso, se você encontrar poste aí

Comment: Eu ainda acho que é possível, se o Excel tiver alguma fórmula para trabalhar com [Integrais](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_integral).

Comment: @Renan o vinicius achou a formula

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fórmula para resolver o exemplo inicial:**

```
=B4*SOMARPRODUTO(B1*(1+B2)^LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&B3)))
```

Considerando que os valores das variáveis estejam nas seguintes colunas:

```
C   => B1
J   => B2
n   => B3
TC  => B4
```

---

**Fórmula para calcular a taxa de custódia no TESOURO DIRETO:**

A taxa de custódia cobrada pelo tesouro direto é provisionada diariamente. Logo, a fórmula acima não se aplica, pois provisiona anualmente. Segue abaixo o desenvolvimento de uma fórmula mais adequada para calcular a taxa de custódia para títulos prefixados do Tesouro Direto (LTN).

Como a taxa é provisionada diariamente, temos que converter as variáveis iniciais para valores diários:

```
J   =>  (J+1)^(1/365)-1
n   =>  n*365
TC  =>  (TC+1)^(1/365)-1
```

Substituindo, a fórmula fica da seguinte maneira:

```
=((B4+1)^(1/365)-1)*SOMARPRODUTO(B1*(1+(B2+1)^(1/365)-1)^LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&B3*365)))
```

Anulando operações opostas, fica assim:

```
=((B4+1)^(1/365)-1)*SOMARPRODUTO(B1*((B2+1)^(1/365))^LIN(INDIRETO("1:"&B3*365)))
```

Há ainda mais um detalhe: a taxa de custódia começa a ser cobrada em D+2. Por isto, alteramos a parte `INDIRETO("1:"&B3*365)` para `INDIRETO("3:"&B3*365)`

**Finalmente, chegamos à fórmula definitiva:**

```
=((B4+1)^(1/365)-1)*SOMARPRODUTO(B1*((B2+1)^(1/365))^LIN(INDIRETO("3:"&B3*365)))
```

**Observações Importantes:**

1. O resultado da fórmula é apenas uma estimativa, pois considera que o valor do título irá evoluir uniformemente de acordo com os juros informados. Porém, na realidade, a evolução do valor do título é influenciada também pela expectativa do mercado em relação ao futuro da taxa SELIC. De qualquer maneira, acredito que seja a melhor forma de estimar o total de taxa de custódia que será cobrado ao longo da aplicação. É um valor bem próximo do real, sobretudo se o vencimento do título não for de muito longo prazo e a SELIC não variar muito. Esta fórmula é muito útil para se poder estimar a rentabilidade real de um investimento em título prefixado do Tesouro Direto.
2. A taxa de custódia cobrada pela BM&FBOVESPA na verdade é 0,3% ao ano.
3. Além da taxa de custódia há também uma taxa cobrada pela instituição financeira intermediária. Geralmente é algo em torno de 0% a 0,3%. Há um ranking de taxas no seguinte link: http://www.tesouro.fazenda.gov.br/ranking-das-taxas
4. Você pode adaptar a fórmula para calcular também (ou juntamente) a taxa total da instituição financeira, pois geralmente é calculada da mesma maneira.

Comment: Boa :D Vou testar aqui depois pra ver se vai funcionar direitinho

Comment: E se solucionou mesmo, marque sua própria resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 2):

> Depois de várias tentativas e muita pesquisa, cheguei a uma conclusão: É impossível reduzir isso a uma unica fórmula no excel.

**O que fazer então?**
Para facilitar sua vida, sugiro que deixe as 3 primeiras colunas separadas para validação.

A primeira coluna irá representar o ano(preencha quantos anos achar necessário), a segunda coluna o montante e a terceira a taxa de custódia paga nesse ano.

> Na segunda coluna, use a função SE para verificar se o ano correspondente da linha é menor ou igual ao periodo. Ex: `=SE(A1<=H2;F2*(1+G2)^A1;0)` nesse caso, caso verdadeiro ele irá calcular o montante, caso falso deixará como 0.

Pronto, agora é só usar a fórmula que você já tem para calcular a Taxa paga na terceira coluna `=B1*I2` como você já verificou na segunda coluna o periodo não precisa verificar novamente, pois o resultado sempre será 0;

Por ultimo use uma célula para calcular o somatória da terceira coluna tendo o resultado final: `=SOMA(C:C)`

> Não é uma formulá para fazer todo o calculo, mas é uma forma de ter o resultado que você quer podendo alterar somente as 4 variáveis que você citou.

Ficará assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Correção**

> - É possivel com a fórmula da resposta do @Viniciusmss

Answer (score 1):

vamos lembrar da somatória de uma progressão geométrica ?

se você tem a série: a^1 + a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^n
a Soma seria: a(a^n -a)/(a - 1)

Se substituir a = 1 + j, no final você terá => (1+j)([1+j]^8 -1)/(j)
O resultado multiplica por R$1000,000 e depois por 3%.

Exemplo: (1+12%)([1+12%]^8 -1)/(12%) = 13,7756563120849
13,7756563120849 * R$ 1000,00 * 3% = 413,269689362547 (Que é o resultado final)

Espero que tenha facilitado a vida de vocês!
abcs.

Comment: Excelente Diogo! Muito obrigado!